# Java ZK framework event After Window onCreate and after Listbox onAfterRender

Tags: java, listbox, rendering, zk

i need to implement a behavior after all components in my `ZK page` are ready this means.

```
button onCreate was set.
window onCreate was set.
listbox firstonAfterRender was fired.

<window onCreate=''>
    <listbox onAfterRender=''>
         <button onCreate=''/>
    </listbox>
    <listbox onAfterRender=''/>
    <listbox onAfterRender=''/>  
</window>
```

i did it on `window onCreate` unfortunately `Listbox(s) onAfterRender` are fired even after `Window onCreate was fired` is something like handle a blocking on each component according by a logic on each one..

there is a way which  a event are fired after `Window onCreate` and after `my listbox or my listboxes **first** onAfterRender was fired??`

any workaround..

there are a bunch of windows which i need to implement this would be great a way of standardizing instead of apply on each one.. this means would be cool apply on a method which all windows share.

Comment: `@Init` or `@DoAfterCompose` in VM/Controller?

Comment: i have try add a composer to it but doAfterComposer is called very early in the call sequence... even after Window onCreate

Comment: look here : http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer